# PHP 5.4 after-install: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unknown option bit(s) set at offset 0

Tags: php, codeigniter, pcre

I recently upgraded my PHP to version 5.4.1 on my Lion OS X 64bit, I'm getting an error thrown in Codeigniter:

```
Severity: Warning

Message: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unknown option bit(s) set at offset 0

Filename: core/Utf8.php

Line Number: 44
```

I Googled the problem, this seems to be a problem with the PCRE lib in PHP, well I followed [this tutorial](http://www.hirmet.com/mac-os-x-lion-upgrade-to-php-5-4) which shows to install pcre with homebrew which I did (I'm running pcre 8.30) and this didn't solve the problem.

I've tried looking around for solutions, but I haven't came across one that helped - is there a method of fixing this PCRE lib problem?

EDIT: Just edited this question to remind me what my installation was:

```
./configure \
--prefix=/usr \
--mandir=/usr/share/man \
--infodir=/usr/share/info \
--sysconfdir=/private/etc \
--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs \
--enable-cli \
--with-config-file-path=/etc \
--with-libxml-dir=/usr \
--with-openssl=/usr \
--with-kerberos=/usr \
--with-zlib=/usr \
--enable-bcmath \
--with-bz2=/usr \
--enable-calendar \
--with-curl=/usr \
--enable-dba \
--enable-exif \
--enable-ftp \
--with-gd \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/X11/ \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
--with-png-dir=/usr/X11/ \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--with-icu-dir=/usr \
--with-iodbc=/usr \
--with-ldap=/usr \
--with-ldap-sasl=/usr \
--with-libedit=/usr \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-mbregex \
--with-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock \
--with-readline=/usr \
--enable-shmop \
--with-snmp=/usr \
--enable-soap \
--enable-sockets \
--enable-sysvmsg \
--enable-sysvsem \
--enable-sysvshm \
--with-tidy \
--enable-wddx \
--with-xmlrpc \
--with-iconv-dir=/usr \
--with-xsl=/usr \
--enable-zip \
--with-pgsql=/usr \
--with-pdo-pgsql=/usr \
--with-mcrypt=/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error using CakePHP 2.1 using preg_replace. I have the same setup as you (Lion, PHP 5.4.1, pcre 8.30). There are some conditions where I get this error and others where preg_replace doesn't work at all. So, it's not an issue limited to these variables with Codeigniter.

Comment: I just noticed something on my end. Even though I have version 8.30 installed through homebrew and I reference it's path during config, phpinfo() shows version 8.02! I bet that's the problem. See if that's the case on your end. Now I just have to figure out how to get it to compile using 8.30.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did, I don't understand why PHP isn't picking it up even when you specify the directory `/usr` for pcre even the homebrew installation of pcre is there.

Comment: I deleted the homebrew pcre installation and downloaded 8.30 from their website. I compiled it using the directory prefix /usr/local and I am now in the process of recompiling PHP. I'll let you know if it produces any changes (takes about 45 mins to compile php on my end).

Comment: No luck. I found some other posts that recommended re-installing apache from source. They suggested running a test where in the command line PHP uses the right version, but with Apache is does not. This was the case for me, so I plan to build Apache from scratch tomorrow. I'll post if I have any helpful results.

Comment: Unfortunately, compiling Apache, PHP and PCRE directly from source didn't fix the issue either. `phpinfo()` is still showing pcre version 8.02. Will post if something else comes along though.

Comment: @ScottHarwell That is really weird, perhaps it should be classified as a bug when PHP gets compiled?

Comment: I don't know. I just compiled and installed PHP 5.3.11 to see if changing back to the older version would help. It did not. I removed all pcre files in `/usr/local` and reinstalled.  No luck.  So, I'm not sure quite where the problem lies.  It's too bad because my dev environment is pretty hosed without pcre working with php and apache.

Comment: Hmm, that's a shame really. I think this problem should go towards bugs.php.net. I'll make a report and link to this page as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get PHP 5.4.1 working with PCRE version 8.12 (which is the version included in PHP 5.4.1 I believe).  After all the back and forth listed in the question's comments, I decided to compile PHP without the PCRE flags and let PHP just use it's defaults. By using the defaults, it compiles with 8.12.

Now, a follow up questions is, of course, WHY this happens. I would still expect 8.30 to be compiled with PHP with the flags I provided. But, at this point, I am just happy to have the thing working.

Below are the config options I got to work in case you want to try it from your end.

```
./configure \
--prefix=/usr \
--mandir=/usr/share/man \
--infodir=/usr/share/info \
--sysconfdir=/private/etc \
--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs \
--enable-cli \
--with-config-file-path=/etc \
--with-libxml-dir=/usr \
--with-openssl=/usr \
--with-kerberos=/usr \
--with-zlib=/usr \
--enable-bcmath \
--with-bz2=/usr \
--enable-calendar \
--with-curl=/usr \
--enable-dba \
--enable-exif \
--enable-ftp \
--with-gd \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/X11/ \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
--with-png-dir=/usr/X11/ \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--with-icu-dir=/usr \
--with-iodbc=/usr \
--with-ldap=/usr \
--with-ldap-sasl=/usr \
--with-libedit=/usr \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-mbregex \
--with-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock \
--with-readline=/usr \
--enable-shmop \
--with-snmp=/usr \
--enable-soap \
--enable-sockets \
--enable-sysvmsg \
--enable-sysvsem \
--enable-sysvshm \
--with-tidy \
--enable-wddx \
--with-xmlrpc \
--with-iconv-dir=/usr \
--with-xsl=/usr \
--enable-zip \
--with-pgsql=/usr \
--with-pdo-pgsql=/usr \
--with-mcrypt=/usr
```

Comment: Excellent!  Glad it worked for you too.  If you happen to run across a similar issue down the road and figure out how to compile it with the updated PCRE version, then please post and let me know!

Comment: I’m having this issue, but my `./configure` command fails if I don’t specify the PCRE path (just says “clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)”).

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue by updating PHP and PCRE on my Linux machine using `yum update`.

PHP was updated to version 5.3.17 and PCRE was updated to version 8.21-5.3amzn1 ( I'm running on an Amazon EC2 instance ).

Comment: I had the same problem and this solution also resolved this issue. I'm on Mac OS X with MacPorts. I used `port upgrade outdated` to get the latest versions of PHP (5.3.17) and PCRE (8.31 2012-07-06).

Comment: When you use a package manager, you are getting the precompiled versions of those apps.  So, it would be expected that the versions passed through the package manager would work together.  However, this answer doesn't really apply to the question since the person asking is trying to compile newer version of php than available via a package manager or through Apple.  The problem here arises when trying to use any PCRE version and then trying to compile PHP from source on a mac.

Answer (score 0):

Recompile httpd.
Before that make sure you have only one version of pcre on your system.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution was near to what @bigZero proposed.

I couldn't make it work on brew because when I tried to install pcre v8.12 on brew it was not possible because it was (maybe) erased from the repository. I mean, it is shown on `brew versions pcre` but when I tried to install it failed to download from ftp://ftp.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/software/programming/pcre/

So I had to download the pcre 8.12 source code from http://www.pcre.org, compile it and install it. I used the following configure: `./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-utf8 --enable-unicode-properties`

I tried to recompile php (in my case 5.4.10) without the `--with-pcre-regex` option (as suggested by @scott-harwell. But it failed while compiling. Than I added `--with-pcre-regex=/usr/` and it finally worked.