# Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: unknown option bit(s) set at offset -1

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace, warnings, php-5.4

I recently upgraded my dedicated server to Apache 2.4.6, MySQL 5.5.32, and PHP 5.4.21. Now on my website I get this error:

> Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: unknown option bit(s) set at offset -1 in /home/champion/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php on line 295

Here is the code from shortcodes.php on line 295:

```
$text = preg_replace("/[\x{00a0}\x{200b}]+/u", " ", $text);
```

Is the preg_replace function not compatible with the new PHP 5.4.21?

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338234/php-5-4-after-install-preg-match-compilation-failed-unknown-option-bits-s

Answer (score 3):

Updating the PCRE version to 8.21 has fixed the problem.