# Warning Error on Godaddy server

Tags: wordpress

Recently i purchase new Linux server in godaddy.  i transfer my wordpress website in my one another server to godaddy server. but in godaddy server display one Warning error message: "Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: unknown option bit(s) set at offset 0 in /home/flyfabrics/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php on line 309"  and this message also display in inner pages.

My wordpress site is work perfect in my old server with out any warning message. But this warning message is only display in this godaddy server.

if any one know how to remove this warning message in godadddy server then please know me.

Answer (score 0):

you might be running a different version of php/pcre on this server in comparison to your old server.

See this post here:
[PHP 5.4 after-install: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unknown option bit(s) set at offset 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338234/php-5-4-after-install-preg-match-compilation-failed-unknown-option-bits-s)